# Como enviar os resultados de vários comandos Findstr para apenas um arquivo.txt?

Tags: windows, batch, windows-10, bat

Estou criando um [bat](/questions/tagged/bat) que tem vários comandos **`"Findstr"`**

Como posso enviar os multiplos resultados obtidos pelos comandos "`Findstr /i /c:Strings` para um mesmo `arquivo.txt`?

```
dir/s/b C:\Users > C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt

findstr /i /C:"Click"  C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt > C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSFileScanResult\ResultCLICK.txt
findstr /i /C:"Macro"  C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt > C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSFileScanResult\MACRO.txt
findstr /i /C:"Client" C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt > C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSFileScanResult\CLIENT.txt
findstr /i /C:"Hack"   C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt > C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSFileScanResult\HACK.txt
findstr /i /C:"Reach"  C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt > C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSFileScanResult\REACH.txt
findstr /i /C:"jnat"   C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt > C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSFileScanResult\JNAT.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Tens opções usando os redirecionadores **[`> >>`](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**:

- **`>Sobrescrever no arquivo`**

  - Vai escrever no arquivo independente do arquivo existir ou não, no caso de não existir o seu arquivo, o operador redirecionador vai criar o arquivo com o conteúdo redirecionado, em existindo, o operador vai substituir o conteúdo existente no arquivo.

- **`>>Acrescentar no arquivo`**:

  - Vai escrever no arquivo independente do arquivo existir ou não, no caso de não existir o seu arquivo, o operador redirecionador vai criar o arquivo com o conteúdo redirecionado, em existindo, o operador vai acrescentar o conteúdo redirecionado ao arquivo.

> *Tem como enviar o resultado de vários findstr para um arquivo de texto?*
>
> - `>tem >>Sim!`

```
dir/s/b C:\Users > C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt

findstr /i /C:"Click"  C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSFileScanResult\MesmoArquivo.txt
findstr /i /C:"Macro"  C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSFileScanResult\MesmoArquivo.txt
findstr /i /C:"Client" C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSFileScanResult\MesmoArquivo.txt
findstr /i /C:"Hack"   C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSFileScanResult\MesmoArquivo.txt
findstr /i /C:"Reach"  C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSFileScanResult\MesmoArquivo.txt
findstr /i /C:"jnat"   C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt >> C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSFileScanResult\MesmoArquivo.txt
```

---

+**Obs.: 1.** Você pode também usar multiplas strings no seu comando `Findstr` e para um mesmo arquivo num só comando:

```
dir/s/b "C:\Users" >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt"
>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\SSFileScanResult\File.txt" %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /il "Click Macro Client Hack Reach jnat" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt"
```

---

+**Obs.: 2.** Caso o não seja necessário criar o arquivo **`"..\SSHelpToolFiles.txt"`**, seria uma obter as strings direto do comando `dir, assim escrevendo/salvando um arquivo:

```
dir/s/b "C:\Users"| >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\SSFileScanResult\File.txt" %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /il "Click Macro Client Hack Reach jnat"
```

+**Obs.: 3.** Caso o não seja necessário filtrar nomes de pastas, seu comando `dir` pode se restringir a listagem delas com `/a:-d` (atributo -menos diretorio).., ou usar o comando `where /recursivo`, onde a saida se da com o caminho complete (equivale `dir /b`), e se aplica somente aos arquivos...

```
where /r "C:\Users" * | >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\File.txt" %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /il "Click Macro Client Hack Reach jnat"
```

+**Obs.: 4.** Já que o seu comando está fazendo o uso uma de variável de ambiente do Windows (`C:\User\%UserName%`) para então compor o caminho no comando, que tal usar algo mais curto (`%UserProfile%`)..

```
C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt > C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSFileScanResult\ResultCLICK.txt
      %UserProfile%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt > %UserProfile%\Desktop\SSFileScanResult\ResultCLICK.txt
```

+**Obs.: 5.** Como um amigo sempre diz, *"use aspas e tenha paz com você mesmo!"*... evite erros ao usar variáveis que podem conter "nome composto [espaços]"

```
 :: path\variável :: 
    %UserProfile%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt
    C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt 

:: "path\variável" ::
    "%UserProfile%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt" 
    "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt"
```

+**Obs.: 6.** Existe a também a opção de usar redirecionamentos por `> blocos (de commandos)`...

```
dir/s/b/a:-d "C:\Users" >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt" && (
    findstr/iC:"Click"  "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt"
    findstr/iC:"Macro"  "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt"
    findstr/iC:"Client" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt"
    findstr/iC:"Hack"   "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt"
    findstr/iC:"Reach"  "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt"
    findstr/iC:"jnat"   "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt"
    ) >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\Output_No_Mesmo_Arquivo.txt" 

rem :: ou... :: 
( where /r C:\Users * |findstr/iC:"Click" /iC:"Macro" /iC:"Client" /iC:"Hack" /iC:"Reach" /iC:"jnat"
) >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\Output_No_Mesmo_Arquivo.txt" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt"

rem :: ou... :: 
( where /r C:\Users * |findstr/il "Click Macro Client Hack Reach jnat"
) >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\Output_No_Mesmo_Arquivo.txt" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SSHelpToolFiles.txt"
```

---

#### Referencias e documentações para consultas:

*Quais são os recursos e limitações não documentados do comando FINDSTR do Windows?*

❖ **[em pt-BR](https://qastack.com.br/programming/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman)**     |    ❖ **[in en-US](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman)**

*Ajuda com o* **`Findstr /?`**:

❖ **[em pt-BR](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr)**     |    ❖ **[in en-US](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

#### Consultas complementares `// in en-US`:

- **[Redirecionamento](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, `>>`, `<<`, etc.
- Variaveis de ambiente não documentadas

  - **[`%__AppDir__%`](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)  | [`%__CD__%`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6137)**